# How to compare range of date in C/C++?

Tags: c++

Is there any system defined function to compare two dates in C/C++?

Thanks

Comment: C or C++? Also, what format are the dates in?

Comment: How are you representing dates? If you're using something simple like 'seconds since epoch', you can use simple math comparisons.

Comment: I need the format like these mm/dd/yyyy hr:min:sec

Comment: To bad you are not using ISO standard dates YYYY-MM-DD. Then you could use a string compare. :-)

Comment: Another question where karthik/user692270 accepts @karthik 's answer. Stop this faked upvote-farming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. convert the date (you pick the format) to seconds since the start of the era. use strptime and mktime.
2. compare the two time_t (seconds) values.
   example using MON-DD-YYYY format:

CODE:

```
#include <time.h>
time_t to_seconds(const char *date)
{
    struct tm storage={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    char *p=NULL;
    time_t retval=0;

    p=(char *)strptime(date,"%d-%b-%Y",&storage);
    if(p==NULL)
    {
            retval=0;
    }
    else
    {
            retval=mktime(&storage);
    }
    return retval;
}

int main()
{
  char *date1="20-JUN-2006";
  char *date2="21-JUN-2006";
  time_t d1=to_seconds(date1);
  time_t d2=to_seconds(date2);

  printf("date comparison: %s %s ",date1,date2);
  if(d1==d2) printf("equal\n");
  if(d2>d1)  printf("second date is later\n");
  if(d2<d1)  printf("seocnd date is earlier\n");
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is my favorite date class (C++ only, not C):

http://howardhinnant.github.io/date.html

With this you can write programs like:

```
#include "date.h"
#include <cassert>

int main()
{
    using namespace gregorian;
    date d1 = thu[last]/mar/2011; // last Thursday in March 2011
    date d2 = mar/31/2011;       // March 31, 2011
    assert(d1 == d2);            // The last Thursday in March 2011 is 3/31/2011
    d1 += month(1);              // last Thursday in April 2011
    assert(d1 > d2);             // d1 is later than d2
    assert(d1 == month(4)/28/2011); // d1 is now Apr. 28, 2011
}
```

The software is free to use.  You don't even have to credit anyone.  1 [header](http://home.roadrunner.com/~hinnant/date.h), 1 [source](http://home.roadrunner.com/~hinnant/date.cpp).

**Update**

Latest version of this software is here: https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html

Comment: this is so beautiful. Congratulations! So elegant, so .. just beautiful. ;-)

Comment: @Phil:  Thanks Phil.  Glad this library has been helpful for you.  The C++ committee firmly and enthusiastically rejected it. In case it is helpful to you, I've retreated my stance to a small collection of chrono-compatible date algorithms upon which anyone could efficiently build a date class.  This should allow more date API experimentation among a wider audience, including yourself.  These low-level date algorithms are found here: http://home.roadrunner.com/~hinnant/date_algorithms.html .  Please feel free to use these algorithms however you wish -- public domain.

Comment: It was quite late for me last night when I came across this and posted my comment. I now believe though it fell short on reflecting how excited and impressed I was after seeing this. It is really rare to see in engineering field something that both does the job well and that's self explanatory. This solution does it all in a semantically / linguistically correct way that makes sense. This is one of those rare, wonderfully crafted ones and it covers such an important subject: dates. Given that my comment did reach, I wanted to congratulate you proper. Committee's stance a shame. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by Bo Persson's comment:

```
bool compare_DD_MM_YYYY_dates(std::string date1, std::string date2)
{
  assert(date1.size()>=10);   assert(date2.size()>=10);
  // ISO-fy dates
  date1 = date1.substr(6,4) + date1.substr(3,2) + date1.substr(0,2) + date1.substr(10);
  date2 = date2.substr(6,4) + date2.substr(3,2) + date2.substr(0,2) + date2.substr(10);
  return date1 < date2;
}
```

If not fast enough, don't concatenate the substrings, but compare them directly.